# Make an control to always have top alignment in Grid in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gridview, xamarin.android

I have a grid with two columns and two rows. In the second column, there is an Editor and it can expand horizontally as more lines are added to it. When it does the control in the first column (in this case a checkbox), also slides down to the middle. Like this,
[image]

I have tried setting the margin as 0 but that does not work. I don't seem to find any way to force it to always be top aligned.

Here is my code for adding children to the grid,

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemViewList.Count; i++)
{
     ItemGridView.Children.Add(ItemViewList[i].CheckBox, 0, i);
     ItemGridView.Children.Add(ItemViewList[i].Editor, 1, i);
}
```

I am creating a checkbox like this,

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox()
{
   IsChecked = isChecked,
   ClassId = index.ToString(),
   Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
};
```

and Editor like this,

```
Editor editor = new EditorTransparent()
{
     Text = value,
     FontSize = 18,
     AutoSize = EditorAutoSizeOption.TextChanges,
     BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
 };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: perhaps if you actually posted your code we could help you

Comment: use `VerticalOptions` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options